# Open.ai (adobe illustrator) file as a PDF

Tags: android

Is it possible to load .ai files and open them programmatically?

I wanted to convert .ai files to pdf files and want to show it.I know how to do it in iOS but don't know how to acheive it in android.

any tutorial link or suggestion would be appreciable.

Answer (score 1):

To open a .Ai file it needs to have PDF Embedded in it, That`s an option you get when saving a .Ai file through Adobe Illustrator (include PDF Compatibility).
If the .Ai file has that, then all what you need to do is rename it to .PDF instead of .Ai, then open it using a PDF Viewer like: http://www.mupdf.com/